# Limit of integral with respect to parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to find $$\lim_{p \to +0} \int \frac{1}{x^{(p+1)}} dx $$. p is a positive real number. Limit and integral does not seem to be commutative operations. I don't know when I can push the limit inside the integral. There is a similar question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral but there exponent is an integer.

Comment: `Limit[Integrate[1/x^(p + 1), {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> 0 < a < b], 
 p -> 0 , Direction -> "FromAbove"]`

Comment: `Limit[Integrate[1/t^(p + 1), {t, 1, x}], p -> 0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AsymptoticIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticIntegrate) for this purpose:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[1/x^(1+p), x, p->0]
```

> Log[x]

For higher order terms you can use:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[1/x^(1+p), x, {p, 0, 3}]
```

> Log[x] - 1/2 p Log[x]^2 + 1/6 p^2 Log[x]^3 - 1/24 p^3 Log[x]^4

Comment: How to understand the result of `Series[Integrate[1/x^(1 + p), x], {p, 0, 1}]` in 12.1.1.0 on Windows 10, i.e. $-\frac{1}{p}+\log (x)-\frac{1}{2} p \log ^2(x)+O\left(p^2\right) $? Isn't it a bug?

Comment: @user64494 It's not a bug. The indefinite integral is only defined up to a constant, and `-1/p` is a constant with respect to the integration variable.

Comment: Carl Woll:Think of $p\to 0$.